# How can I archive a directory in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to archive a directory with all subdirectory and files. But the below code doesnt work properly. It just archived files and folders, not content of folders ! How can I solve this ?

```
my @files = glob( $BACKUP_PATH.'website/*' );
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();
$tar->add_files(@files);

my $date = DateTime->now(time_zone=>"local");
$tar->write($BACKUP_PATH.$websiteFolderName."/".$date->dmy('-')."-".$websiteFolderName.".tar");
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question was asking how to use Archive::Tar. This question already has that, but there is something wrong with the logic in OP's implementation.

Comment: Have you checked what `@files` contains?

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger? That is the place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob` ([perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)) does not recurse into subdirectories. You need to take care of that yourself or use some module like [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find):

```
use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find qw(find);

my @files;
find( { wanted => sub { push @files, $File::Find::name } }, $BACKUP_PATH.'website');
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();
$tar->add_files( @files );

my $date = DateTime->now(time_zone=>"local");
$tar->write($BACKUP_PATH.$websiteFolderName."/".$date->dmy('-')."-".$websiteFolderName.".tar");
```

Comment: It doesnt work. It throws an error : Cant stat .....  No such file or directory at test.pl on line 24  :  the line -->    find( { wanted . ..... ..

Comment: @Revenge: Yeah, sorry - stupid copy/paste error, the trailing `/*` must be removed.

Comment: Or, better yet: [**`File::Find::Rule`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule)

Comment: Not my downvote, but you ** Omit `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` ** Omit `use DateTime` ** Don't declare or define `$BACKUP_PATH` or `$websiteFolderName` ** Build file paths with string concatentation ** Don't test your solution

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks for the input.

Comment: @zb226 wasn't me. I just thought I'd add a link to FFR. FF is still a valid--and AFAIK the most performant method out there.

Comment: @Axeman: I really dislike `File::Find::Rule` because its syntax is so unmemorable and inexpressive

Comment: @Borodin, I think it was hard for me at first as well, and required a bit of ramp-up, but now it's pretty much what I reach for.

Comment: @Axeman: I've never seen it in production code, and hope not to. Have you looked at the source? It's really nasty stuff that picks at the internals of Perl just to get itself started. Beware

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd write a bells-and-whistles version of this because I was so disappointed with the accepted solution. I thought I'd show you what was possible and what I believe is proper

I've made these changes

- I'm using [`Time::Piece`](http://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) to get the date stamp for the file name. It's a core module, and all that is necessary to generate a `%d-%m-%Y` datestamp. [`DateTime`](http://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) is non-core, and a huge amount of code to load for such a simple purpose

  *By the way I've used a `ymd` format instead of `dmy`. If you want it the way you wrote your own code then you can change it back, but `ymd` names are useful because they sort in date order*
- I've used `catdir` and `catfile` from [`File::Spec::Functions`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec::Functions), the procedural interface to the core [`File::Spec`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec) library. It saves worrying about whether one variable has a slash at the end and another at the beginning, and makes for clearer code because it avoids all those nasty string concatenations
- I've used `make_path` from [`File::Path`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Path) to ensure that the destination directory actually exists
- Since the paths to the files to be archived are stored in an array anyway there no reason not to use the `create_archive` class method to build and save your files all in one go

  *The second parameter to `create_archive` is a compression method. I have set it to zero to request no compression and maximum speed, but you can enable gzip or bzip compression by passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` or `COMPRESS_BZIP`*

  *Although the module's documentation discourages it, you can also set this parameter to 1 through 9 to indicate a level of gzip compression. If you are archiving text files then I highly recommend that you use 1 or 2 here. Passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` results in a gzip compression level of 9, which is by far the slowest and can often result in a *larger* file than lower compressions. A value of 1 will often give you a file one third of the size of the uncompressed archive, while 2 may give you another five percent reduction. After that there is usually very little gain*
- I've added a few log messages to give confidence and inform about the progress of the program. I've also written a little `bytes` subroutine to convert the size of a file to the appropriate power of 1KB to make it more readable

I'm using Windows paths because that's the desk where I happen to be sat. Because of the use of `File::Spec` it should work fine on Linux as well once you have set the paths and file names at the top of the code +

Whether or not you use this, I hope you find it useful

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find qw/ find /;
use Time::Piece;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/ catfile catdir /;
use File::Path qw/ make_path /;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $BACKUP_PATH         = 'E:/Perl';
my $website_folder_name = 'website';
my $website_backup_name = 'website_backup';

print "Making list of files to archive\n";

my $source_dir = catdir($BACKUP_PATH, $website_folder_name);
my @filelist;

find( sub {
    return unless -f;
    push @filelist, $File::Find::name;
}, $source_dir);

printf "List complete - %d files to be archived\n", scalar @filelist;

my $tardir = catdir($BACKUP_PATH, $website_backup_name);
make_path($tardir, { verbose => 1 } );

my $date = localtime()->ymd;
my $tarfile = catfile($tardir, "$date-$website_backup_name.tar");
print qq{Writing archive to "$tarfile"\n};

my $success = Archive::Tar->create_archive($tarfile, 0, @filelist);
printf "Archive written successfully - %s\n", bytes(-s $tarfile) if $success;


sub bytes {
    my ($size) = @_;

    my @prefix = ( '', qw/ K M G T P E / );

    my $pow = 0;
    while ( $size >= 1024 ) {
        $size /= 1024;
        ++$pow;
    }

    sprintf "%.0f%sB", $size, $prefix[$pow];
}
```

### output

```
Making list of files to archive
List complete - 6602 files to be archived
Writing archive to "E:\Perl\website_backup\2016-01-07-website_backup.tar"
Archive written successfully - 7MB
```